# how to rewrite this Scala withColumn when condition

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

I have some Scala code that works when I run manually in Spark EMR, but I get errors when I try to compile in Eclipse.

```
val tmp_df2 = tmp_df1.withColumn("col_one", when($"col_two" === "good", "bad").otherwise($"col_one"))
```

When I run "Maven install" it says "error: not found: value when". But I know the code works in EMR.

So, is there another to specify that condition without using "when"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to import the spark function as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```